# Scanning File with VirusTotal API

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new in Python so this might be a noob question to some. I am DEVing in Python 3.0

I keep on encountering an error:

```
File "scan.py", line 7, in module
    json = postfile.post_multipart(host,selector,fields,files)
File "C:\Python32\lib\postfile.py", line 10, in post_multipart
    content_type, body = encode_multipart_formdata(fields,files)
File "C:\Python32\lib\postfile.py", line 42, encode_multipart_fordata
     body = CRLF.join(L)
TypeError: sequence item 8: expected str instance, bytes found
```

When I try to run this code to connect and scan a file with the VirusTotal API. This code is similar to their example in the site.

```
import postfile
host = "www.virustotal.com"
selector = "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan"
fields = [("apikey", "123123123123123123123123123")]
file_to_send = open("android-icq.apk", "rb").read()
files = [("file", "android-icq.apk", file_to_send)]
json = postfile.post_multipart(host, selector, fields, files)
print (json)
```

The postfile.py contents are as follows:

```
import http.client, mimetypes

def post_multipart(host, selector, fields, files):
    """
    Post fields and files to an http host as multipart/form-data.
    fields is a sequence of (name, value) elements for regular form fields.
    files is a sequence of (name, filename, value) elements for data to be uploaded as files
    Return the server's response page.
    """
    content_type, body = encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files)
    h = http.client.HTTP(host)
    h.putrequest('POST', selector)
    h.putheader('content-type', content_type)
    h.putheader('content-length', str(len(body)))
    h.endheaders()
    h.send(body)
    errcode, errmsg, headers = h.getreply()
    return h.file.read()

def encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files):
    """
    fields is a sequence of (name, value) elements for regular form fields.
    files is a sequence of (name, filename, value) elements for data to be uploaded as files
    Return (content_type, body) ready for httplib.HTTP instance
    """
    BOUNDARY = '----------ThIs_Is_tHe_bouNdaRY_$'
    CRLF = '\r\n'
    L = []
    for (key, value) in fields:
        L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
        L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % key)
        L.append('')
        L.append(value)
    for (key, filename, value) in files:
        L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
        L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"' % (key, filename))
        L.append('Content-Type: %s' % get_content_type(filename))
        L.append('')
        L.append(value)
    L.append('--' + BOUNDARY + '--')
    L.append('')
    body = CRLF.join(L)
    content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % BOUNDARY
    return content_type, body

def get_content_type(filename):
    return mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0] or 'application/octet-stream'
```

Any ideas on the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like those examples are written in Python 2. You're using Python 3.

Part of the rationale behind Python 3 was the removal 'cruft' which had built up over the years of Python's development, so it was allowed to break backwards compatibility in some places.

See here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I was able to make their other samples work. It is just this specific example that I could not get to run. 

I used the 2to3 tool to convert 2.x code to 3. 

If i still wont get this to work then i will consider going to 2.x python.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Ive switched to 2.7 python and the code worked fine. It wasnt a solution but at least it worked! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python-requests.org/ provide cleaner interface to make HTTP 1.1 queries:

```
import time
import requests
import json

md5url = "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report"
r = requests.post(requrl, data = {"apikey": apikey, "resource": md5})
print(json.loads(r.text))
print(json.loads(r.text)["positives"])
time.sleep(15)

scanurl = "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan"
r = requests.post(scanurl, data = {"apikey": apikey}, files = {"file": (name, open(name, "rb"))})
print(json.loads(r.text))
print(json.loads(r.text)["permalink"])
time.sleep(15)
```