# Python module not exist

Tags: python, pdf, scanning

I'm using python to scan a pdf file by online antivirus so I used
import postfile

but there is an error:

> ImportError: No module named postfile

could any one help me?

Comment: The most probable answer: the library you are trying to use is in an improper place. There are plenty other options, but without more information it's hard to provide any constructive answer ...

Comment: Anthing to do with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870961/scanning-file-with-virustotal-api

Comment: I'm trying this .................................


>>> import postfile
>>> host = "www.virustotal.com"
>>> selector = "http://www.virustotal.com/api/bulk_scan_file.json"
>>> fields = [("key", "1fe0ef5feca2f84eb450bc3617f839e317b2a686af4d651a9bada77a522201b0")]
>>> file_to_send = open("test.txt", "rb").read()
>>> files = [("file", "test.txt", file_to_send)]
>>> json = postfile.post_multipart(host, selector, fields, files)
>>> print json
{"scan_id": "cd1384c10baa2d5b96f397b986e2a1fc9535d2ef0e185a113fc610eca1c6fb0e-1271623480",
 "result": 1}

Comment: postfile isn't part of the standard python library so you must install it somehow before using it.

Comment: what should I install ??

Comment: Guys, just because _you_ don't understand the question, doesn't mean there's not enough info for others to solve the issue. The answer I provided below is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/public-api/) docs.  It *explicitly* mentions needing to copy [this code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306/) into a local file called `postfile.py`